# How to do AjaxControlToolkit ComboBox client side event

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have created the AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox from C# like below code.

```
       AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox ddllst = new AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox
        {
            ID = "ddl_" + key,
            Width = 197,
            AutoCompleteMode = AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBoxAutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend,
            DropDownStyle = AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
        };
```

Here I want to add the client side onchange event in JavaScript.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I understood this circumstances. Thank you for removing such kind of text in the question.